# Liquibase modifyDataType fails on Mysql

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I don't seem to be able to execute a type modification on a Mysql 5.7.10 instance (it works with H2 though).

Here are the changeset steps that are involved with the regarded field:

Creation:

```
<column name="last_modify_time" type="bigint">
    <constraints nullable="false" />
</column>
```

Modification:

```
<modifyDataType tableName="USER" columnName="last_modify_time" newDataType="timestamp" />
```

the error msg in Mysql is

```
Invalid default value for 'last_modify_time' [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE USER MODIFY last_modify_time timestamp]
```

Manually modifying the the request to the following works:

```
ALTER TABLE USER MODIFY last_modify_time timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I don't really understand why Mysql needs the default value. Maybe it's an edge case with the version 5.7.10 (using the default configuration options).
In any case Liquibase should be able to handle it.

I've tried to add/remove default value prior to the `modifyDataType`, without success.

Answer (score 0):

when you are modifying type of a column using liquibase which is non nullable ... you have to first make it nullable and then modify it use safe modify

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work out. The error was still there.

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that an exactly identical modification on a field named `create_time`, placed right before, didn't cause any problem. Swapping the two changsets order did solve the problem.

```
<changeSet id="11" author="author">
    <comment>rename last_modify_time to last_modified_date and change type to timestamp</comment>
    <modifyDataType tableName="USER" columnName="last_modify_time" newDataType="timestamp" />
    <renameColumn tableName="USER" oldColumnName="last_modify_time" newColumnName="last_modified_date" columnDataType="timestamp" />
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="12" author="author">
    <comment>rename create_time to created_date and change type to timestamp</comment>
    <modifyDataType tableName="USER" columnName="create_time" newDataType="timestamp" />
    <renameColumn tableName="USER" oldColumnName="create_time" newColumnName="created_date" columnDataType="timestamp"/>
</changeSet>
```

I still can't explain what happend, I'm happy enough to get it working. If someone wants to reproduce the error I'd be happy to help.